# Get JSX from imported React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

For the purposes of documenting our library, I want to convert a React Component function to JSX. For example, if we have a rendered Button component, I want to show the code for how it's constructed.

One solution could be to read `Button.jsx` as plain text but I feel like there should be a better solution.

```
// Button.jsx
export const Button = (props) => (
  <button {...props}><Icon name={props.icon}/>{props.children}</button>
)
```

```
// ButtonDocs.jsx
import { Button } from 'components/Button';

const Docs = (props) => {
  
  const renderedButton = <Button icon='home'>Hello</Button>


  // Here I'd expect this function to return something like:
  // `<button><Icon name="home"/>Hello</button>`
  const buttonJSX = someFunctionToGetJSX(renderedButton)

  return (
    <div>
      {renderedButton}
      <code>
        {buttonJSX}
      </code>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Well, this question doesn't really make sense because the component can do arbitrary things, for instance `if (someCondition) return someJsx else return someOtherJsx`. The concept of "the JSX of a component" is simply not a meaningful concept. The source code is the only thing that makes senses.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. I think the question is more about how to get the render tree in JSX-like syntax given some component & props? Similar to how React DevTools displays the tree

Comment: If we render the component first I think this is a little more realistic. Edited the sample code to be a little more clear

Answer (score 0):

Do this in Button component

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const buttonRef = useRef();
  const [jsxEl, setJsxEl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let jsxArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buttonRef.current.children.length; i++) {
      jsxArray.push(`${buttonRef.current.children[i].innerHTML}`);
    }
    jsxArray.join(",");
    setJsxEl(jsxArray);
    props.onJsxFunc(jsxEl);
  }, [buttonRef]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div ref={buttonRef}>
        <button {...props}>
          <Icon name={props.icon} />
          {props.children}
        </button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Then in ButtonDocs component do the below.

```
// ButtonDocs.jsx
import { Button } from 'components/Button';

const Docs = (props) => {
  
  const renderedButton = <Button onJsxFunc={(el) => showJsxElements(el)} icon='home'>Hello</Button>
  const jsxCode = useRef();


  const showJsxElements = (el) => {
    jsxCode.current.innerText += `${el}`;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderedButton}
      <code>
        <div ref={jsxCode}></div>
      </code>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That get's the HTML though. If there are descendant React components, I'd like to see those

Comment: @AdamMThompson In that case you have to loop through the elements children, check the updated answer code

Comment: That should work, yeah. But here's where React Refs get frustrating. I don't necessarily have control over the component `Button`, and if it doesn't support `forwardRef` then I can't use this approach unfortunately. EDIT: I guess I can add the ref to a wrapper element

Comment: You are likely never going to get it as expected because React adds its own synthetic sugar to elements on render. But what you can do is call the ref on the button page and pass the innerText value through a prop function to the Docs component

Comment: Okay check the final update, that should get you  much closer to what you need